# Haskell trees: how to get binary tree with leaf as any type?

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

Created a binary tree structure, values can be either a node with 2 branches, a leaf or empty. I've not specifically defined leaf to be a certain type so I can create trees with all leaves as integers or all as string, but how can I get it so that it accepts a mix of the 2 types, so a tree with leaves as integers aswell as strings?

```
data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Example of what I want: a node with 2 leaves, `leaf1 = "a string"` `leaf2 = 5`
My current problem is that `leaf1` and `leaf2` need to be same type so both either integers or both strings. I get an error If I do a mix.

Comment: You should "move" the problem to the `a` parameter. You can define a `Tree (Either Int String)`, so then a `Leaf` can contain `Left 3`, or `Right "string"`.

Comment: The need to do this stems more from the ability to do it (easily) in other languages more than from an *actual* need to do it.

Comment: Why do you need different types in the leaves?

Comment: What if I wanted the leaf to be any type ?  @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @BerryScott: if these can be any type, then the tree is "useless", since then you can not perform any operation on the tree at all, since the type is a "contract" what you can do with the values.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Its part of "homework" i have done a height and others functions on this tree, I have these functions working as it is for when leaf is just an integer or just a string I wish to do it for leaf when its anytype.

Comment: "A value of any type" is not a useful concept in Haskell the way it is in non-statically-typed scripting languages.

Comment: @BerryScott: I think the question is where the *quantifiers* in the statements are placed, you have constructed a tree that can encapsulate values of any type. All the leaves have the same type, but we can pick any type for `a`. If the leaves have all different types, then there is not much (well nothing at all actually) we can do with these elements.

Comment: @BerryScott You might want to double-check what the exercise actually requires. A `height :: Tree a -> Int` function will work with `Tree String`, `Tree Int`, and so forth -- that, however, doesn't mean you can have `String` and `Int` elements in the same tree.

Comment: @duplode the testcase examples that were given on the exercise show the tree given to the height function containing integer and bool type leaves. Functions need to be polymorphic

Comment: @BerryScott "[...] show the tree given to the height function containing integer and bool type leaves" -- What does that tree look like in the example?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you’ll likely find your code to be significantly simpler if you get rid of the `Leaf a` constructor and use `Node a Empty Empty` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Practically you can't create trees in Haskell that can contain *any* type. However, you can define custom types with multiple constructors like this:

```
data Val a b = Int a | String b deriving (Show, Eq)
```

You then use the `Val` type to create trees containing two types:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Eq)
let v = Node (String "eh") (Leaf (Int 12)) (Leaf (Int 123))
:t v
v :: Num a => Tree (Val a String)
```